# Using a USB port to connect to a microprocessor to program?

Tags: usb, programming, microprocessor

I am designing a led information board, I want to use a USB port to connect to the micro processor to program it, is it possible to use a USB port to do this? I am using a genie 14.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to the datasheet for the device. Do you mean a [Genie C14](http://www.rapidonline.com/electronic-components/genie-microcontroller-c14-ic-13-6002)?

Comment: Genie C14 on the proper breakout bord can be programmed with a USB to serial cable: http://www.rapidonline.com/electronic-components/genie-pcb214-c14-project-kit-13-6013 -- What are your reasons to use the Genie? Most arduinos come with USB out of the box.

Comment: I'm not using a arduino, I am using the chip because its easy to use I am a beginner.

Comment: If you are committed to the Genie C14 you are restricted to whatever it supports, so this is not question about USB programming in general. Perhaps @Posipiet can write an answer based on his/her comment.

Comment: I assume your question is "can the data for my LED information board be loaded by a program running on a **GENIE 14** over USB". Is that correct? So then is your further question, "how do I write a program to load that LED data"? I assume your question is **not** "are their any microcontrollers which can load data over USB?" However, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the general case.  I don't know of any micros that have so much USB logic built in that they can natively come up as a device and accept data to write to their program memory.

This can be done if the right program is previously loaded into the micro.  That program then reads data from the USB and writes it to its own program memory.  However, if that program isn't already in memory then this method can't be used to program the micro.

At least once initially, somehow the program has to be loaded into the micro using its native programming interface.  Those are usually JTAG or SPI-like.  You'll have to read the specs for your particular micro.

Sometimes micros are available that already have a program loaded into them for the purpose of loading other code in over a common communication interface, like UART or USB.  Perhaps you "genie" thing is one of those, but since you haven't provided any specs we can't tell.

Even if you get a micro that comes pre-loaded with such a program, it's a good idea to have the ability to program the micro using its native interface.  Stuff happens.  If your experimental program accidentally scribbles on the right part of program memory, then you're hosed without a native programmer.

Comment: There are many microcontrollers that can do this. They usually have the bootloader code in ROM. I have personally used the LCP1343 and some Tiva C series chips, though many people on this site have mentioned other ones that have this capability.

Comment: Genie's are pre-programmed PIC MCUs. They contain a bootloader. They are often programmed with a USB to serial cable. Genie is a well known brand in UK education, for example [Genie Microcontrollers](http://www.rapidonline.com/Genie-Microcontrollers), so the OP likely thinks we are all familiar with it. Merry Christmas.

Comment: @gbulmer: I'm familiar with PICs, but never heard of this "genie" thing before.  It's not my job to do searches and go digging up specs that the OP should have provide links to.

Comment: I'm not surprised you haven't of heard of "Genie". It is designed for teaching at secondary (or even primary) school (in the UK?), with its own proprietary programming system. IIRC it is easy to do simple things, but a dead-end if what you want to do isn't easy. I agree, we shouldn't need to dig up datasheets. I suggested one in a comment, but that was because I think there are several parts with similar names, but the OP didn't respond. We do what we can to help :-) "We can lead a horse to water but can't make it drink" (unless we use two bricks, and that can hurt our thumbs :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, if I'm interpreting your question correctly. Many of Atmel's SAM series have built-in usb and a bootloader, meaning that you can program and talk via serial through just a usb connector soldered to the pins of the chip. Dead easy.

Comment: The NXP LPC11Uxx series can do this as well -- I have a devboard for an LPC11U3x part and have bootloaded it that way personally.